# MUI TextField select option shows the values as a row instead of a column after update?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, uitextfield

So for some reason now the TextField select from MUI is showing the options as a row instead of a column

[image]

Any reason why this is happening ?

Code:

```
<TextField 
               select
               margin="normal"
               value={colegio}
               helperText="Seleccione la sede"
               onChange={handleChangeColegio}
               >
                   {sedes.map((option) => (
            <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
              {option.label}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
          </TextField>
```

All this is wrapped in a Container -> Paper -> Box

```
"dependencies": {
"@emotion/react": "^11.4.1",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
"@material-table/core": "^0.2.6",
"@mui/icons-material": "^5.0.1",
"@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.54",
"@mui/material": "^5.0.4",
"@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.0.0",
"@mui/styles": "^5.0.1",
"@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.0.0-beta.7",
"@mui/x-data-grid-generator": "^5.0.0-beta.4",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
"date-fns": "^2.25.0",
"devextreme": "21.1.5",
"devextreme-react": "21.1.5",
"firebase": "^8.10.0",
"material-table": "^1.69.3",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.1",
"react-scripts": "4.0.3",
"react-select": "^4.3.1",
"styled-components": "^5.3.1",
"web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
```

},

**UPDATE**
Everything working!